# BirdWatching app 'incompatible pointer types initializing'

Tags: initialization, incompatibility

I just started coding and as I followed Apple's article ['Your Second iOS App:Storyboard'](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CodeListings/CodeListings.html), I had a warning that says 'incompatible pointer types initializing Birdsighting *__strong with an expression of type NSString *' from the following code:

```
detailViewController.sighting = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
```

Answer (score 0):

well you are trying to say (IT SEEMS):

NSString *stringInCurrentTableViewRow = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
   BirdSighting *yourObject = stringInCurrentTableViewRow;

---

you are sure the dataController doesnt contain Strings ;)